# HTML phone number pattern in <input>

Tags: html, validation, pattern-matching, forms

I'm working on a HTML form and and I have this input tag for a phone number. 
I would like the phone numbers inserted in the textbox to match the following format: +389-xxx-xxx , such as e.g. +389-111-222 .
but I've struggled so far to make the pattern attribute.
Can someone give me some suggestions to validate the input using only HTML5? Tnx <3

Answer (score 0):

How about the following pattern:

```
<input type="text" pattern="(\+389)[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{3}">
```

The pattern looks for +389 followed by two consecutive - and 3 digits.

Comment: Yes, it fit its purpose! 

 pattern ="^\+389-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}" works equally good.

Although, thank you!